Converging PDEs as hydrodynamic limits of converging particle processes
Suppose that some interacting particle process $\{X^i_t\}_{i=1}^n$ has a hydrodynamic limit which is a PDE
$$\rho_t = L \rho + f\quad \quad \quad (1) $$
where $L$ and $f$ are possibly nonlinear. By interacting particle process, I mean that each $X^i_t$ follows some SDE where the drift and diffusion terms may be a function of the other particles (or their mean). By hydrodynamic limit, I mean that the empirical distribution $\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X^i_t}$ converges in probability to the solution $\rho$ of $(1)$.
Suppose also that we have a sequence of PDEs whose solutions converge to the solution of $(1)$, say, solutions $\rho^n$ satisfying the PDE
$$ \rho^n_t = L^n \rho^n \quad \quad \quad (2) $$
such that $\rho^n(x,t) \rightarrow \rho(x,t)$ in some appropriate sense. Suppose also that for each $n$, there is a particle process $X^n_t$ whose hydrodynamic limit is $(2)$. (Pardon the double usage of the superscript on $X_t$; $i$ and $n$ mean different things.)
Can we determine whether the SDEs governing $X^n_t$ converge somehow to the SDEs governing $X_t$?
Related question: if we know that some processes $X^n_t$ converge to a limiting process $X_t$, then do we know that the hydrodynamic limits converge?

This question needs some clarifications. While defining the hydrodynamic limit, do you mean $n$ copies of particles satisfying the same SDE that governs $X_t$, do you mean independent copies? In that case, the empirical distribution will converge simply to the $Law(X_t)$ . About your question, if $\rho_n$ and $\rho$ are close say in Wasserstein distance or something, $Y^{n}$ and $Y$ are processes with the Law $\rho^n$ and $\rho$, then they are close as well.

@Raghav true. editing now, thanks.
